# What are good/practical strategies for performing disk IO in a packet recorder application receiving several Gbit/s of traffic?

Tags: c, linux, performance, io, network-programming

Consider the following scenario:

[image]

A traffic generator generates 20 Gbit/s of network traffic and sends
it to a traffic recorder utilizing two 10 Gbit links. Inside the traffic
recorder all packets should be written to a single file.

That's what I'm trying to do from a higher level perspective. Now have a look
at the internal structure of the packet recorder:

[image]

Both NICs use Intel DPDK (http://dpdk.org/) for dealing with incoming packets.
Therefore all incoming traffic is stored in mbuf structs of a preallocated
pool of mbuf structs which lives in upserspace. So far everything's working
fine. All packets reach the application. It's even possible to memcpy each
packet to some bigger buffers, if there's a need to aggregate the data.

The difficulties I'm having are with writing the data to the file. I tried to
indicate that with the red flash between the application and the file.

None of the approaches I took so far has been working. Some of those are:

1. Memcpy'ing packets into a bigger (preallocated) buffer and write to the file when the buffer is full.
2. Same as 1. but with seperate threads for buffering and writing using multiple buffers.
3. Similar to 2. but using a Threadpool
4. Asynchronous writing with Linux AIO
5. Memory mapping the file

During execution of the apps I used iostat for monitoring disk utilization. Most of the time disk utilization wasn't very high or the disk wasn't writing at all.

My thoughts are that it should continuously write data to disk as fast as
possible. With packets coming in at a speed of 20 Gbit/s the disk needs to
write 2.5 GByte/s (theoretical).

One important thing to note is that the disk needs to be fast enough to even
handle that amount of data. I measured the IO performance using fio 
(https://github.com/axboe/fio) and it should be no problem, if done right, to achieve enough speed. Doing it right is the problem though.

What are good strategies/solutions for maximizing disk IO in such a scenario?

How can disk utilization be increased?

Any source (literature, blog, ...) which is related to this topic would be
very welcome as well.

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**
This is some example code for approach #1. I stripped the code down a little bit, but there really isn't going on much more. I tried running it on a different number of threads, with different buffer sizes, fwrite instead of
write etc.

```
 1 static int32_t store_data(struct storage_config *config)
 2 {
 3   sturct pkt *pkts[MAX_RECV];
 4   char *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
 5   uint32_t bytes_total = 0;
 6
 7   while (config->running) {
 8      uint32_t nb_recv = receive_pkts(pkts);
 9      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nb_recv; ++i) {
10         if (bytes_total + pkts[i]->len > BUF_SIZE) {
11            write(config->fd, buf, bytes_total);
12            bytes_total = 0;
13         }
14         memcpy(buf + bytes_total, pkts[i]->data, pkts[i]->len);
15         bytes_total += pkts[i]->len;
16      }
17   }
18   return 0;
19 }
```

The other approaches write in a similar fashion. The thread pool variation for example uses multiple buffers instead of one and passes that buffer to another thread. So the call to write in line 11 is extracted into it's own function, a thread would be tasked with IO instead on that line and the store_data() function would use one of the additional buffers.

**Edit 2:** In reference to Andriy Berestovskyy's answer I incorporated his
suggestion and used writev. The application now looks like this:

[image]

On each of the two rx cores, which are DPDK-lcores, runs the following code:

```
while (quit_signal == false) {
    nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(conf->port, 0, pkts, RX_RING_BURST_SIZE);
    if (nb_rx == 0) { continue; }

    for (i = nb_enq; i < nb_rx; ++i) {
        len = rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(pkts[i]);
        nb_bytes_total += len;
        iov[iov_index].iov_len = len;
        iov[iov_index].iov_base = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkts[i], char *);
        rte_pktmbuf_free(pkts[i]);
        ++iov_index;
        if (iov_index >= IOV_MAX) { 
            if (writev(conf->fd, iov, IOV_MAX) != nb_bytes_total) {
                printf("Couldn't write all data\n");
            }
            iov_index = 0;
            nb_bytes_total = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

(RX_RING_BURST_SIZE is 32 because by default thats the maximum value DPDK enforces and I don't know how to change it. I don't know if that would make a difference though)

When both NICs receive about 10 Gbit/s (1.25 GByte/s) of traffic about half the data is lost, when packet size is 1024 byte. If packet size is 64 byte performance is even worse and about 80% of the data is lost. Which makes kind of sense, because smaller packets means more syscalls and the rx ring gets filled faster. What doesn't make sense is, that the drives don't write at full speed most of the time, according to iostat.

Comment: Assuming "*None of the approaches I took so far has been working.*" means "None of the approaches I took so far were fast enough": Dare to show the code  (to slow) for writing?

Comment: I don't really understand this.: your app is just moving buffer pointers/indexes around between one I/O channel and another.  Should not be any issue with code, since there's not much going on, code-wise.

Comment: @alk You're right: "None of the approaches I took so far were fast enough" is what it means and I added some sample code.

Comment: What is your *hardware*?  Motherboard, disk controller, hard disks especially.  Crap commodity hardware - especially motherboard and/or disk controller (because nobody thinks about those but they can kill performance) - can make this task impossible.  Use good, fast hardware and the software design might not even matter.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too broad, but overall:

1. Avoid file system, i.e. use raw partitions/devices.
2. Have a look at SPDK. It is like DPDK, but for the storage (NVMe):
   http://www.spdk.io/

EDIT 1:

In the code snippet you have provided, you should use single writev() call instead of loop + memcpy + write(). Also it is not clear from the snippet what is the *actual* burst size. It is better to consolidate few small bursts and write them at a single syscall.

EDIT 2:

1. There is a bug in the code: rte_pktmbuf_free() before the actual write.
2. MAX_IOV is 1024 on my platform, so it is better to consolidate few bursts up to IOV_MAX before call the write.
3. To avoid syscalls on the polling core, use another lcore to do the write. Use a single producer single consumer ring buffer between the cores.
4. Since you already familiar with fio and its performance is ok for you, use the same approach as fio does, i.e. same IO engine, type etc.
5. Create a test app which writes the same buffers in a loop, i.e. eliminate the RX part of your code and measure just the writing performance.

Comment: I need to write to a file, so raw partitions/devices isn't a possiblity and SPDK is definitly something I'll look into. Why is the question to broad?

Comment: @Marco to narrow down the question, you should provide some code ;) IMO if you see no performance differences in the listed (quite different) approaches, you might not use those approaches optimally. Please see the updated answer with some comments regarding your snippet.

Comment: Have a look at Edit 2. I tried to be more specific and added the improvements you suggested :) @Andriy Berestovskyy

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't memcpy() - build IOV from pkt mbuf data and defer pkt mbuf free after it is written to disk.
2. Don't use read()/write() in DPDK polling core. You can use [aio](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html) or better (but harder to code but all packets mught be queued for write with only one syscall) [IO_LISTIO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lio_listio.3.html). All the data (IO vectors or aiocb_lis) can be embedded in pktmbuf itself using `priv_size` argument of `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()` so no additional allocation is needed.

Use SPDK as last resort. It is great library but also very demanding.